# Angular ng-switch with ng-show not respecting DOM order

Tags: angularjs

I'm coming to Angular from a jQuery / Backbone background so I'm new to Angular. Anyway, so I'm trying to show/hide divs based on select box values. Basic stuff I know.

The problem is that with the code block below even though `<div ng-show="designer">` is the last element in the DOM it shows up before both of the switch-when statements. Moving it around makes no difference.

```
<select ng-model="designer">
  <option value="designerYes">Yes</option>
  <option value="designerNo">No</option>
</select>

<div ng-switch on="designer">
  <div ng-switch-when="designerYes"...>
  <div ng-switch-when="designerNo"...>
  <div ng-show="designer">
</div>
```

I suspect the problem is related to when the events switch and show events are fired but I'm not sure how the best way to troubleshoot or fix the problem. Any ideas on a solution?

**UPDATE**: The solution (for my case at least) was to not mix ng-switch and ng-show. The first answer right. Because the switch statements aren't in the DOM they are appended after the already available ng-show div.

Here's the answer...

```
<select ng-model="designer">
  <option value="designerYes">Yes</option>
  <option value="designerNo">No</option>
</select>

<div ng-show="designer == 'designerYes'"...>
<div ng-show="designer == 'designerNo'"...>
<div ng-show="designer">
```

This will always show the 3rd DIV when a selection is made and conditionally one of the others based on value.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or plunker sample?

Comment: In that case you can remove the `ng-switch on="designer"`

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo You're right. Thanks. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `designer` will be undefined until you make a selection. So the 1st two won't be rendered I guess. Can you initialize it with one of the values and see if that helps?